# Query optimization and concatenation

Tags: sql, oracle, full-text-search, oracle-text

I'm running often this query and I would like to optimize it.

```
select
    number || ' ' || name
from tasks
where upper(number || ' ' || name) like '%VALUE%'
```

I've created an index, but the it took the same time as without the index

```
create index name on tasks (upper(number || ' ' || name))
```

Are there any other options ?

Comment: Did you check the query plan? Is the index even used?

Comment: The index is not used

Comment: The index won't be used because you have a percent before VALUE, you're forcing a full-scan and there's not much you can do about it. Why are you concatenating stuff together anyway? What sort of values would VALUE be and do you obtain it concatenated? Why are you looking for VALUE anywhere in the string?

Comment: it's a query where the user does a search by the task number or the task name. I do not know prior the execution. also the value can be in any part of the name or number.

Comment: Have you considered using "CTXCAT index"? There is lots of good information out there, but this is one I've found useful: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/ctxcat-primer-090555.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using text indexes:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24435/overview.htm#i1007403

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure that the condition is selective enough to justify using an index then you might like to try promoting an [index fast full scan](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29505_01/server.1111/e16638/optimops.htm#i52044) with the following:

```
select /*+ INDEX_FFS(tasks your_index_name) */
       number || ' ' || name
from   tasks
where  upper(number || ' ' || name) like '%VALUE%'
```

Edit:

I seem to recall that another way of promoting an IFFS is:

```
select number || ' ' || name
from   tasks
where  rowid in (
         select rowid
         from   tasks
         where  upper(number || ' ' || name) like '%VALUE%')
```

Surprisingly barely less efficient that the former method.